# run cgi script as a different user

Tags: linux, perl, apache, cgi

I have a tool written in perl which is used by different users in my company. Each user has his/her own disk space allocated to them and they run the tool in their diskspace. This is working fine without any issues. As a next step, I wanted to enable the tool through web and created a web application through which users can run this tool, the issue that i have is, the tool is always run as a single user. I know the user name through authentication, is there a way by which i can run the tool as the user who is running the web application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [suexec](http://enwp.org/suexec).

Also see questions tagged [suexec](/questions/tagged/suexec).

Comment: Thank you. From the description in the wikipedia, this is what i want. will accept it after testing

Comment: This appears to fix the user to run as for a given CGI binary or path.  Is there a way to dynamically choose the user to run as, for instance, if the CGI script authenticates the user and then passes off the user name to suexec?

Comment: Michael, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your follow-up question.